# Yii2 + redis class error

Tags: php, yii, redis, yii2

I have an error when i'm trying to configure Yii2 with Redis:

**Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException**
**The configuration for the "db" component must contain a "class" element.**

[Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html)
and [yii2-redis](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-redis-index.html) was installed with *composer*.

```
# ls -la project_dir/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-redis/
total 116
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 мар 26 13:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  4096 мар 25 14:54 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 18013 мар  1 14:22 ActiveQuery.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 11140 мар  1 14:22 ActiveRecord.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2194 мар  1 14:22 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  6390 мар  1 14:22 Cache.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 22224 мар 26 13:59 Connection.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1622 мар  1 14:22 LICENSE.md
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 14015 мар  1 14:22 LuaScriptBuilder.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  5650 мар  1 14:22 README.md
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  5170 мар  1 14:22 Session.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   891 мар  1 14:22 composer.json
```

I just edit: project_dir/config/db.php

```
 <?php
/*return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2basic',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];*/
    return [
    'components' => [
    'redis' => [
    'class' => 'yii\redis\Connection', tied to replace with "'class' => 'yii2-redis\redis\Connection',"
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 6379,
    'database' => 0,
               ],
                    ]
            ];
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add valid configuration for `db` component for correct initialization:

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',

            ...
        ];

        ...
    ],
];
```

Read more in [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-configurations.html).

Comment: any clue for `The configuration for the "cache" component must contain a "class" element.` i configured the cache class like this `'class' => 'yii\redis\Cache'`

Answer (score 1):

Add the below lines in config/main.php

```
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\redis\Cache',
        'redis' => [
            'hostname' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ]
    ],
```

and for using that you have to use it in the following way

```
yii::$app->cache->redis
```

and the redis functions after that like

```
yii::$app->cache->redis->hset('check',email,key);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'components' => [
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\redis\Cache',
        'redis' => [
                'hostname' => 'localhost',
                'port' => 6379,
                'database' => 0,
        ]

    ],
],
```