# Yii2 redis Not instantiable

Tags: redis, yii2

I trying to use redis cache in my Yii2 project, but getting this error

> "Failed to instantiate component or class "yii\redis\Cache"."

Here is my configurations

```
'cache' => [
    'class' => 'yii\redis\Cache',
    'redis' => [
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'port' => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ]
]
```

when this below code executed the error appear

```
$cache = Yii::$app->cache;
```

i have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32435610/10191136) way but still got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update your yii2-redist

```
composer require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-redis:"~2.0.0"
```